# Sum palette with pm3d

Tags: gnuplot, gradient, palette

In a multiplot I draw 3 maps with different palette color (see code below).
I want in the fourth square of my multiplot the sum of the three others, i.e. red parts, blue parts, green parts, and a combination of red+blue+green depending on the values of columns 14, 15 and 16.

```
set view map; set size square
set xlabel "delta mu Al"
set ylabel "delta mu Mn"
set zlabel "fraction atomique"

set multiplot layout 2,2
set title "Fer"
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "red")
splot "res700.dat" u 3:4:($16/3456) t "Fe"  with pm3d

set title "Alu"
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "green")
splot "res700.dat" u 3:4:($14/3456) t "Fe"  with pm3d

set title "Mn"
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "blue")
splot "res700.dat" u 3:4:($15/3456) t "Fe"  with pm3d

unset multiplot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rgb variable`. With black as the no-signal colour, this gives:

```
set view map; set size square
set xlabel "delta mu Al"
set ylabel "delta mu Mn"
set zlabel "fraction atomique"

set isosample 100
Fe(x,y)=x*y
Al(x,y)=(1-x)*y
Mn(x,y)=x*(1-y)

set multiplot layout 2,2
set title "Fer"
set palette defined (0 "black", 1 "red")
splot [0:1][0:1] "++" u 1:2:(Fe($1,$2)) t "Fe"  with pm3d

set title "Alu"
set palette defined (0 "black", 1 "green")
splot [0:1][0:1] "++" u 1:2:(Al($1,$2)) t "Al"  with pm3d

set title "Mn"
set palette defined (0 "black", 1 "blue")
splot [0:1][0:1] "++" u 1:2:(Mn($1,$2)) t "Mn"  with pm3d

set title ""
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(255*r) + 256 * int(255*g) + int(255*b)
unset colorbox
splot [0:1][0:1] "++" u 1:2:(rgb(Fe($1,$2),Al($1,$2),Mn($1,$2))) t "" with pm3d lc rgb variable

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted white as no-signal. So I changed the `rgb` function as: `rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(255*r) + 256 * int(255*g) + int(255*b)`

Comment: You unsetted the color bar. Is it possible to draw a triangle: A red corner labelled as "Fer", a green corner as "Alu" and the last one as "Mn" ?

Comment: Yes, you can create one as a separate plot within multiplot, whose coordinates should be entered explicitly. I think for clarity you should ask a separate question if you need assistance with this.